# Java Applet init method

Tags: java, parameters, applet

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class MyApplet extends Applet {
        static public int m,n,p,k;
    public void init () {
        m=Integer.parseInt(getParameter("m"));
                n=Integer.parseInt(getParameter("n"));
                p=Integer.parseInt(getParameter("p"));
                k=Integer.parseInt(getParameter("k"));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            int m1,n1,k1,p1;
            System.out.println(m+""+n+""+""+k+""+p+"44");
            m1 = (args.length>0) ? Integer.parseInt(args[0]) : m;
            n1 = (args.length>1) ? Integer.parseInt(args[1]) : n;
            k1 = (args.length>2) ? Integer.parseInt(args[2]) : k;
            p1 = (args.length>3) ? Integer.parseInt(args[3]) : p;
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("App");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLocation(200,200);
            Board p;
            try {
                    p = new Board(m1,n1,k1,p1);
            } catch (Exception ex) { p = new Board(5, 5, 1, 1); }
            frame.add(p);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I will explain first: I have those 4 parameters in HTML file, but if someone gives his own arguments then they have priority, and catch is if someone gives wrong arguments, like letters instead of numbers. Point is, I don't think init method is ever called, as you can see I added print in main method and it always prints zeroes, even when I set 'm' in init manually for 15 or something, still prints 0. Is it because it goes straight to main method, ignoring init? How can I prevent that for happening, I really need those HTML parameters to work.

Comment: Well you never actually create a `MyApplet`

Comment: One question: do you know what an **Applet** is?

Comment: What you want is a _hybrid applet/application_. `init()` must be manually invoked from `main()` when running as an application.

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing. 3)  An applet typically does not have a `main(String[])` method, and it is not called during normal applet execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use your class *as* an `Applet` then the applet container hosting it is responsible for instantiating it and invoking the lifecycle methods on it at appropriate times (`init()`, `start()`, `stop()`, and `destroy()`).  Note in particular that **the `main()` method has nothing to do with running an instance as an `Applet`** -- it's the entry point for running your class directly on a VM as an *application*.

On the other hand, if you run your class as an application, nothing in its `main()` method does anything that would cause `init()` to be invoked.  The `main()` method does not even create an instance that `init()` could be invoked *on*.